# Im keep getting this error: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop]

Tags: xml, spring, namespaces, aop

I'm currently learning Spring. The error I'm getting seems to be a common one and I've read a lot of posts dealing with the same problem. I've added the dependency to my pom.xml and the schema to my Beans.xml. The versions I'm using are the same, and after a clean install the aop is present in the one-jar file. When I run the one-jar file, I end up with the same error.

Any ideal what more I can do to fix this?

[image]

(had to make a screenshot, stackoverflow did not want me to add the xml code to my post)

The stack trace:

```
Mar 26, 2022 10:38:46 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5fcfe4b2: startup date [Sat Mar 26 10:38:46 CET 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 26, 2022 10:38:46 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop]
Offending resource: class path resource [Beans.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.packs.app.App.main(App.java:9)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation=
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">
<bean id="knight" class="com.packs.beans.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
</bean>
<bean id="quest" class="com.packs.beans.SlayDragonQuest">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
</bean>
<bean id="minstrel" class="com.packs.aspect.Minstrel">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
</bean>
<aop:config>
<aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="embark" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark" method="singBeforeQuest"/>
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark" method="singAfterQuest"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no need for screenshots of code. Just like other code types, XML can be posted inside a code block. Please study the markdown syntax help in order to find out how to do that. It is super easy. Click "edit" so see how I did that for your console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the very file which you decided **not** to post, `Beans.xml` - why the upper-case "B", by the way? Maybe you are missing something like

```
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
```

and/or

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
```

in your `<beans ...>` declaration, which e.g. could look like this in a working case, depending on what kind of stuff you want to use and configure in your Spring project:

```xml
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
  "
>
```

---

**Update after the OP posted a link to his GitHub project:** I cloned your project and ran it. It is not true that you still have the same error. The XML file works now. The new error I see reads (I added some line breaks):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]:
  BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0':
    Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4f6ee6e4' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
      Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4f6ee6e4':
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
        Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
          org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
(...)
```

So Spring cannot find a class from AspectJ weaver, which must be on your classpath for Spring AOP to work. If you look into the *spring-aop-4.1.0.RELEASE.pom*, you will see:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Scope `optional`! That means, you explicitly have to declare the dependency in your own POM for it to be on the class path. Add this to your POM (let us use the latest 1.8.x version):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Now your application works like a charm and prints:

```
Fa la la, the knight is so brave!
Embarking on quest to slay the dragon!
Tee hee hee, the brave knight did embark on a quest!
```

BTW, as you seem to just start with Spring, I recommend you to use a more recent version (maybe also Spring Boot) and maybe rather learn about annotation-driven configuration than XML-defined one, even though it is definitely good to know both, if you have to deal with legacy applications. But first, you can follow your tutorial and learn the basics. Actually, a pure Spring application without any container or application server starts much more quickly than e.g. a Spring Boot app.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put my version of the Beans.xml file in the post. I also tried your version , but I get the same error again. plz take a look at the code on github: https://github.com/LucasHartman/SpringAction/tree/main/SpringExamples

Comment: No, you do not get the same error again, my suggestion fixed your problem. Now you have another one, because your POM is incomplete. See my updated answer.

Comment: I added de aspectj depenency to my pom file, but it still wound work for me. Your probably right about me trying to using annotation-driven configuration through an XML. This goes way above my head. I think I just going to try it with a java-config file and stay in my convert-zone. 

Btw, I first wanted to learn Spring Boot, but that book recommend to start out learning Spring first.

Comment: Then you must have changed something else since you pushed the code to GitHub. I simply added the dependency, and it worked immediately. You need to learn to not change too much at once and lose the overview. Just check out the commit you shared with me, add the dependency and be happy. BTW, the book recommends the right thing. Basics first! Boot is on top of Spring or helps with pre-configured use cases, but hides the basics. So you better understand those first. Take your time, you will get there step by step.